# Why do the Fifth Brother and Seventh Sister work together?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

In *Star Wars: Rebels*, why do the Seventh Sister and Fifth Brother work together? It's made very clear they don't like or respect each other, so it probably isn't by choice. Additionally, the Grand Inquisitor and Eighth Brother both worked alone, so there doesn't seem to be any rule that Inquisitors must operate in pairs.

So if they don't want to and seemingly aren't forced to, why do they always work together?

Answer (score 1):

I would think it´s because they can complement each other´s strengths, with the Fifth Brother being more experienced and with a stronger Force connection, and the Seventh Sister a better lightsaber duelist and with a better strategic mind. The Eighth Brother was tracking Maul and would possibly notify Vader before acting on it if successful...

Comment: I agree, they complement each other.